# Dividing values inside dict of 2d dict by another dicts values matching that key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

These dictionaries are long and I need to loop through multiple key values. 
For a short example. In the long run I need to divide all the numbers by their appropriate count to get the average.

```
counts = {'A':10, 'B':14}
totals = {'A':{'atk':20,'str':20,'def':20}, 
          'B':{'atk':140,'str':140,'def':140}}
```

I need to update totals so that in the end

```
totals = {'A':{'atk':2,'str':2,'def':2}, 
          'B'{'atk':10, 'str':10,'def':10}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a dict comprehension using `O(1)` dict lookup

```
>>> {k1: {k2: v/counts[k1]  for k2, v in d.items()} for k1, d in totals.items() }

{'A': {'atk': 2.0, 'str': 2.0, 'def': 2.0},
 'B': {'atk': 10.0, 'str': 10.0, 'def': 10.0}}
```

---

Can always  expand the comprehension..

```
f = {}
for k1, d in totals.items():
    sub = {}
    for k2, v in d.items():
        sub[k2] = v/counts[k1]
    f[k1] = sub
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use dict comprehension yet, but that looks great.

Comment: @satoshinakomoto can always expand the into loops